# Removing duplicates from list of dicts throws Exception?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following list in python:

```
[('admin', '', {'type': 'telnet'}), ('admin', '', {'type': 'telnet'})]
```

Where I'm trying to remove duplicates (something is considered duplicate if it's **100%** the same) so I wrote:

```
my_list = list(dict.fromkeys(my_list))
```

But sometimes I get the following exception:

```
unhashable type: 'dict'
```

How may I fix this?

Comment: This is list of tuples

Comment: well, for starters, you cannot use a `set` with `dict` objects

Comment: @buran thanks, so how to remove duplicate tuples?

Comment: ...to get unique you could use the `set()` function. But will have problem with the `dicts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `dict.fromkeys` uses the elements of the list as the keys of the resultant dictionary.  All keys of a dictionary must be hashable.  Your list contains tuples.  Tuples are hashable if and only if all of their elements are hashable.  Dictionaries, which your tuples contain, are not hashable.

For this case, you might be stuck with a crude loop:

```py
unique = []
for elem in my_list:
    if elem not in unique:
        unique.append(elem)
```

Comment: Thanks, But this doesn't mention how to fix the issue without changing the input

Answer (score 1):

If you want check duplicated and remove them. First, convert each element to `str` then use `set` at the end use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) and back them to original like below:

```
lst = [('admin', '', {'type': 'telnet'}), ('admin', '', {'type': 'telnet'}), 
       ('admn', '', {'type': 'telnet'}), ('admn', '', {'type': 'telnet'}),
# --------^^^-----------------------------^^^ duplicated
       ('admin', '', {'typ': 'telnet'}),('admin', '', {'typ': 'telnet'})]
------------------------^^^----------------------------^^^ duplicated
import ast
list(map(ast.literal_eval, set(map(str,lst))))
```

output:

```
[('admin', '', {'type': 'telnet'}),
 ('admn', '', {'type': 'telnet'}),
 ('admin', '', {'typ': 'telnet'})]
```

Comment: Great use of many builtins in the one-liner!

Comment: Could two equivalent dictionaries have different representations under `str`?  I.e., does the order in which the keys were added matter?

Comment: @DanielWalker, OP says : `100% the same`

Comment: Does `100% the same` mean something more than equality?

Comment: I understand Op want check duplicated between `{'typ': 'telnet'}` and `{'typ': 'telnet'}`

Comment: @DanielWalker, I'm happy if you can give me an example.

Comment: Well, yes, it works for the specific example provided.  But, by that logic, `unique_list = [('admin', '', {'type': 'telnet'})]` would be a valid solution.

Comment: @DanielWalker, Yes this is a valid list with one element. and type of element is tuple and tuple have three elements.

Comment: @DanielWalker, If you try this : `lst = [('admin', '', {'type': 'telnet'})];
print(lst[0]); print(lst[0][2])`. you get this : `('admin', '', {'type': 'telnet'}) , {'type': 'telnet'}`

Comment: an interesting method, but uses 4 functions and and import, so although good it is unreadable.  prefer a simple loop and construct a new `unique_list`.

Answer (score 1):

this would work:

```py
my_list = [('admin', '', {'type': 'telnet'}), ('admin', '', {'type': 'telnet'})]

unique_list = []
for i in my_list:
    if i not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(i)

print(unique_list)
```

result:

```
[('admin', '', {'type': 'telnet'})]
```

Comment: ha,  yes.   I notice that 2 or 3 answers came in at the same time. must have been editing simultaneously.  as is @The_spider.  At least there is a consensus.

Answer (score 1):

Any object being set as a dictionary key or a set item, needs to be hashable. hashing means that a python object, like a float number, string or tuple is converted to a unique number. This number allows easy lookup for the dictionary. However, it requires that the hashed element can't be changed, as this would also require the number to change.

Tuples themselves are hashable, as they can't be changed. However, they are only hashable if their content is also hashable. The strings are perfectly hashable, but dictionaries aren't. This means that you can't use dictionaries as dictionary keys.

Thus, the problem requires another solution. The simplest one would be to create a new list and then append every unique item in the list to it:

```py
new_list = []

for x in my_list:
    if x not in new_list:
        new_list.append(x)
```

When you need the change to be in place, meaning that every variable assigned to that list also changes, you can add the following line:

```py
my_list[:] = new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hash a dictionary, that is why you are getting an error. But you **can** convert it to a string, hash that string, use the fact that dictionary keys are unique, and recover their values (which have the original hashes).

```
lst = [('admin', '', {'type': 'telnet'}),
       ('admin', '', {'type': 'telnet'}),
       ('admin', "", {'type': 'telnet'}), ]

lst = list({str(x) : x for x in lst}.values())

print(lst)
# [('admin', '', {'type': 'telnet'})]
```

Comment: This won't work. Consider `{"type": "telnet", "a": 1}` and `{"a": 1, "type": "telnet"}`

Comment: @AndrejKesely: These are not 100% the same. Different order of keys in the dictionaries. The OP did specify: 100% the same. But my answer can be easily adapted to this case by presorting the dictionary keys.